# How do I provide type annotations inline when calling a non-generic function?

Tags: rust

One way I know is to provide the type annotations in Rust is by declaring an intermediate variable so the compiler knows the return type:

```
use std::num::Int
let max_usize: usize = Int::max_value();
println!("Max usize: {}", max_usize);
```

But how can I provide the type annotation "inline"?

For example, I don't expect the following to work unmodified because there's no type annotation at all, but this is the kind of thing I'm after:

```
use std::num::Int
println!("Max usize: {}", Int::max_value());
```

I tried `Int::max_value::<usize>()`, which gives `error: too many type parameters provided: expected at most 0 parameter(s), found 1 parameter(s)` - and that makes sense because `max_value()` isn't generic.

In Scala I would write `myFunction(someDog: Animal)` instead of writing

```
val someAnimal: Animal = someDog
myFunction(someAnimal)
```

Is there equivalent syntax in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so:

```
fn main() {
    use std::num::Int;
    println!("Max usize: {}", <usize as Int>::max_value());
}
```