# How to use `Num::one()` in a generic type?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement the `normalize` functionality of a generic vector, which requires me to use something equivalent to `self.mulf(1.0 / self.length())`.

However, I was unable to generically specify I need 'one' of a any possible type of float using `Float::one()`.

The latter works fine if used in a generic function, but not in a generic type.

**How can I use `Num::one()` within a generic type ?**

#### The Code

The following code should serve as an example to show what I tried already. Also I believe to have seen code that uses `Float::one()` from within a generic trait implementation, but I don't want to 'traitify' my vector to keep it as simple as possible.

```
use std::num::Float;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Copy)]
pub struct Vector<T: Float> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl<T: Float> Vector<T> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn mulfed(&self, m: T) -> Vector<T> {
        Vector { x: self.x * m, y: self.y * m, z: self.z * m }
    }

    fn dot(&self, r: &Vector<T>) -> T {
        self.x * r.x + self.y * r.y + self.z * r.z
    }

    // "the type of this value must be known in this context"
    // fn normalized(&self) -> Vector<T> {
    //     self.mulfed(Float::one() / self.dot(self).sqrt())
    // }
    // "the type of this value must be known in this context"
    // fn normalized(&self) -> Vector<T> {
    //     self.mulfed(Float::one() as T / self.dot(self).sqrt())
    // }

    // "too many type parameters provided: expected at most 0 parameter(s), found 1 parameter(s)"
    // As Float is a trait, this can be expected to not work I guess. It should be able to 
    // use Float::one() from within another trait though.
    // fn normalized(&self) -> Vector<T> {
    //     self.mulfed(Float::one::<T>() / self.dot(self).sqrt())
    // }
}

fn gimme_one<T: Float>() -> T {
    Float::one()
}

#[test]
fn one() {
    // But this works !!
    let v: f32 = gimme_one();
    assert_eq!(v, 1.0f32);
}
```

I am using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (458a6a2f6 2015-01-25 21:20:37 +0000)`.

Comment: See also [How do I provide type annotations inline when calling a non-generic function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28272739/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [bug in type inference](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21634). Until the bug is fixed, you can use the fully-specified UFCS form:

```
fn normalized(&self) -> Vector<T> {
    self.mulfed(<T as Float>::one() / self.dot(self).sqrt())
}
```

Even better, you can use [`Float::recip`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/trait.Float.html#tymethod.recip):

```
fn normalized(&self) -> Vector<T> {
    self.mulfed(self.dot(self).sqrt().recip())
}
```

Comment: This answer is referenced in [Trace Quest 5: Episode 03](http://youtu.be/fg63ZcMnXQE).

Comment: Please note that the referenced issue was fixed on github, but the issue I describe here isn't resolved by that. I tried it with `rustc 1.0.0-dev (7858cb432 2015-02-03 03:44:05 +0000)`, which definitely contains the fix in the referenced issue at least.

Comment: Information [added to issue on github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21634#issuecomment-72654510).

Comment: @Byron thanks for keeping us appraised. I added another solution that is probably even better and understandable.

Comment: You are so welcome ! Besides, the `.recip()`  method truly is what we want here - after all, it's easy to read and gets rid of the hopefully soon to be superfluous type hint.