# Rust type hint for static trait function

Tags: static, rust, traits

Consider this example:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn maybe_new() -> Option<Self>;
}

impl MyTrait for i32 {...}

fn hello() {
    match MyTrait::maybe_new() {
        Some(x) => ...,
        None => ...,
    }
}
```

This fails to compile because there is no way to infer the type of x.  Is there some way to add a type annotation to make this work without having to break the maybe_new() into a let statement like this?:

```
let p:Option<i32> = MyTrait::maybe_new();
match p {
    Some(x) => ...,
    None => ...,
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I provide type annotations inline when calling a non-generic function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272739/how-do-i-provide-type-annotations-inline-when-calling-a-non-generic-function)

Answer (score 3):

See [How do I provide type annotations inline when calling a non-generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272739/how-do-i-provide-type-annotations-inline-when-calling-a-non-generic-function). In your case, it would look like this:

```
match <i32 as MyTrait>::maybe_new() {
    Some(x) => ...,
    None => ...,
}
```